# Client XYZ is configured for secret but secret was not received

Tags: aws-php-sdk

I'm using AWS PHP SDK and I'm getting this error when trying to signup a new user:

`` Error executing "SignUp" on "https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"Client XYZ is configured for secret but secret was (truncated...) ``

I've enabled user signup in the settings. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable the client secret when you create your userPool in cognito

Answer (score 1):

The client side library for Cognito does not support a Cognito app client that has a secret key enabled. This [thread](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3455) on Github helps illuminate the situation a bit, or at least it did for me. If you need a Cognito app client that has the secret key enabled (i.e. to forward your authentication through a load balancer, for example) it appears that you need to use API Gateway instead.